# docker commit apache container to image brings trouble

Tags: php, git, apache, nginx, docker

I have an ubuntu image where i have made some changes. Now i want to commit these changes to a new image but the problem now is, when I run the image 
the error says **"PID[1] already running"**.

So, i thought that i could stop the apache in the container where i have made changes but this crashes (kills) the complete container and the changes are lost.

What i want:

Docker Ubuntu Image + Apache
-> Container -> Some changes on the container -> Save the changes to a new Image -> Make a container out of the new image -> Have the "old image" with my changes in a new container, so i could start every time with my new image.

Are there any hints to get what i want?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run two containers that expose the same port you will have an issue. So every time you try to run similar containers ( like in this case, you have two containers: old and new which do the same thing ) you need to reassign the ports. So `-p 80:80` and `-p 81:80`.

When new image is committed you can always use different tag ( of the same image ) which later you can use as reference.

If you don't want to run two containers at once, just `stop` and `rm` the old container - don't worry, you will still have it's image, which you can spin anytime.

Also, please remember you can't commit attached volumes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the problem still exist.. 

httpd (pid 1) already running